# Armadillo with MKL segmentation fault: installation or linking issue?

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, armadillo, intel-mkl

I have been searching for a while now and nothing allowed me to solve my problem.

I installed the Intel MKL libraries on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine and it is correctly linked to Numpy and Scipy. Now, I wanted to do the same thing using Armadillo in the C++ language. I installed it using the readme.txt instructions provided by the Armadillo project (using `cmake`). I checked that it correctly detected the presence of MKL and it did.
Now I want to check that it works well so I just build a matrix and diagonalize it using the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main()
  {
    wall_clock timer;
    int dim = 100;

    cx_mat C = randu<cx_mat>(dim,dim);
    cx_mat D = C.t()*C;

    vec eigval2;
    cx_mat eigvec2;

    timer.tic(); // Initialize clock

    eig_sym(eigval2, eigvec2, D);

    double n = timer.toc();

    cout << "Elapsed time: " << n << " seconds" << endl;
    cout << eigval2 << endl;

  return 0;
  }
```

which is very basic. The problem is that when I try to run it with a matrix dimension of 500. I get a segmentation error (core dumped) and nothing else. I don't know if this has to do with the linking to MKL or just the Armadillo install. Notice that I don't know how Armadillo "knows" that I want to compile and run using MKL since I also have openBLAS, Lapack and BLAS installed since I just use `g++ example.cpp -o example -O2 -larmadillo && ./example`.

I also tried commenting the `#define ARMA_USE_LAPACK` and `#define ARMA_USE_BLAS` in the "include/armadillo_bits/config.hpp" file and rebuilding everything but nothing has changed. I also tried to look at commenting/uncommenting the BLAS CAPITAL/UNDERSCORE/LONG/ LONG LONG things in the same file but since I don't really know what to do I didn't touch anything.

Do you have any advice on that particular topic? I don't even know if the error has anything to do with the installation...

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is the error also there when you use a matrix size of 10?

Comment: No, not at all.

Comment: It might be because of two reasons 1) there is some bug in compiling `armadillo`  or 2) your PC might not have enough memory.

Comment: Then it is more likely that it is a matter or `armadillo` since I used MKL (with Python) without any problems for bigger matrices.

Comment: I guess the same

Comment: So do you have any clues of how to clean up and debug the `armadillo`installation?

Comment: You can try to use a pre-built `armadillo` package for ubuntu

Comment: Hum, yes but I'm afraid of the interferences between the two installations.

Comment: @Tazwiie - Use OpenBLAS instead of MKL. OpenBLAS appears to be better maintained and developed than MKL. Ubuntu has an OpenBLAS package. More recent versions are here: https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/releases

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Indeed, I considered doing it. I have it installed anyways, I will try it with Armadillo then with I succeed in the installation.

Comment: @hbrerkere what is the best way to make Armadillo work with openBLAS in your experience using the openBLAS from the Ubuntu repository?

Comment: @Tazwiie - It's pretty well explained in the `README` file that comes with Armadillo. See also the [download page](http://arma.sourceforge.net/download.html) and the [questions page](http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html)

Comment: Yes I agree but the explanations in the`README` file were supposed to be helpful for MKL too ...

Comment: Specifically, since I have both MKL and openBLAS (from the Ubuntu repository), I don't know how Armadillo chooses between the two using the installation steps in the `README` file.

Comment: Have a look at `CMakeLists.txt` that Armadillo uses. Alternatively, Ubuntu already has this pre-packaged.  Remove MKL, and then install the OpenBLAS Ubuntu package. Then install the Armadillo Ubuntu package.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is there a way to complety remove my `armadillo` install and start from scratch (possibly from the Ubuntu package).
I don't want to remove MKL since I use it in my Python codes...